# WC()->cart->add_to_cart() Not adding custom text on cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've developed a Woocommerce website for a pizza restaurant and created a theme to customize the pizzas, add, remove and exchange ingredients.

The website was working properly since the last woocommerce update.
Before I was using this code to add the pizza customization text on the product.

```
if ($product_id2 != 0) {
$variation    = array(
    //'variation_id' => $variation_id_pizza_principal,
    'Base Pizza 1' => $base_pizza_principal,
    'Ingredientes retirados Pizza 1' => $ingredientes_retirados_pizza_principal,
    'Ingredientes adicionados Pizza 1' => $ingredientes_adicionados_pizza_principal, 
    'Dueto com a pizza:' => $descricao,
    //'variation_id2' => $variation_id_pizza_secundaria,
    'Base Pizza 2' => $base_pizza_secundaria,
    'Ingredientes retirados Pizza 2' => $ingredientes_retirados_pizza_secundaria,
    'Ingredientes adicionados Pizza 2'  => $ingredientes_adicionados_pizza_secundaria,
    );
    
}
else {
    $variation  = array(
        'attribute_Base' => $string_base_p1,
        'Ingredientes retirados' => $ingredientes_retirados_pizza1,
        'Ingredientes adicionados'  => $ingredientes_adicionados_pizza1,
        );
} 






session_start();
$_SESSION['twf_user_custom_datas'] = $user_custom_data_values;



//Add product to WooCommerce cart.



if( WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id, $variation )) {
    if ($qtt_ingredientes_extra > 0) {
        WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $id_ingrediente_Extra, $qtt_ingredientes_extra);
    }
   
    global $woocommerce;    
    
    $cart_url = wc_get_cart_url();

    $output = array('success' => 1, 'msg' =>'Added the product to your cart ' .  , 'cart_url' => $cart_url );
} else {
    $output = array('success' => 0, 'msg' => 'Something went wrong, please try again');
}
```

At the moment the products are added correctly and everything is calculated well but the customization line is not showing under the product on the cart.

Does anyone have an idea if there are any changer on WC()->cart->add_to_cart()?

The text that I'm trying to show is a free text and not an product attribute.

Thank you :)

Comment: Your question seems to be missing [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), since variables are used that are not defined anywhere? In any case, it's easier to use hooks as opposed to custom code you've added in a template file (I'm guessing?) because that's not clear in your question either. 
See for example [Display message below product name on WooCommerce cart page if user has bought product before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67936152/11987538) answer code. So please update your question with more details

Comment: The sample of code is inside of a script called by AJAX on the server to add the item to the cart. All the variables are returning all the data that are supposed to return. Before the update the variable array $variation was shown under the product name on the shopping cart